# Moving first file in folder to another folder

Tags: python

I am trying to move the first file in a folder  into another folder using python. I am using `shutil` in order to do  this.

I know that the following will move the whole `S` folder into the `D` folder. but how do I choose only the first file within the folder?

```
S = '/Users/kitchensink/Desktop/Sfolder'
D = '/Users/kitchensink/Desktop/Dfolder'
shutil.move(S, D)
print("moved")
```

Comment: Determine the "first file", then use shutil.move to move it.

Comment: sorry i should have said that the file will be a variable. i wont know the name of the file in the folder.

Comment: Do you mean the filename will be in a variable? Use `S = f"/Users/kitchensink/Desktop/Sfolder/{filename}"`

Comment: The order of files in directories on most OSs is arbitrary — so saying the "first" file is ambiguous.

Comment: this throws an error saying NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` to find the files in a folder. For example if you want to have a list with all files in SFolder you can do this:

```
import glob
s_files = glob.glob('/Users/kitchensink/Desktop/Sfolder/*')
```

To get the first file, simply take the first element from `s_files`.
After this you can still use shutil to do the actual moving.